# interpreting c structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Considering the following `c` code:

```
typedef struct ELE *tree_ptr

struct ELE {
   long val;
   tree_ptr left;
   tree_ptr right;
};
```

I believe `ELE` encapsulates a single node of a binary tree. Each node has some 32-bit value(val), a `pointer` to a left node, and a `pointer` to a right node.

Can someone confirm that my interpretation is correct?

Also, is `ELE` just an arbitrary variable name or some convention used to name a `struct`?

edit:

What if there was a c program that generated the following 3 lines of assembly code:

```
movq     %rbx, -24(%rsp)
movq     %rbp, -16(%rsp)
movq     %r12, -8(%rsp)
```

Are these 3 lines making room for the 3 elements of the struct on the stack?

Comment: That edit seems to me to be a totally _different_ question, unrelated to the original. You'll actually get a better response if you ask it as a different question, with a little more context. That assembly code could be generated by a hundred different pieces of C source :-) And none of those instruction allocate space on the stack for anything, since they don't change the stack pointer `rsp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would most likely be `ELEment`, one element of the collection.

A few other points to consider:

1. Your `typedef` needs a semicolon at the end.
2. The C standard doesn't guarantee that `long` integers are 32 bits.
3. The type `tree_ptr` indicates that it probably *is* a binary tree but all you know for sure is that it's a structure containing a `long` and the two pointers to the same type as the structure. It may well be a doubly-linked list if the coder that put it together was deranged or sadistic enough :-)

Comment: Thats what my intuition was telling me, I just wanted to make sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ELE` is the so called *tag* of the struct. Tags reside in a separate namespace from other names in C. (other namespaces are those for members of respective structs and unions, labels and the rest (like variable names, function names, etc.))

So `ELE` (most likely for "Element") refers to this struct inside of the namespace for structs/unions/enums.